# Sending an OAuth 2.0 POST request with custom headers + attribute values using C# for Inoreader

Tags: c#, .net, post, oauth-2.0, uwp

I'm trying to perform user authentication via OAuth 2.0 for a UWP C# Inoreader app I'm working on. Documentation on steps to follow can be found here: https://www.inoreader.com/developers/oauth.

I've no idea on how to code this part:

> **Obtaining access and refresh tokens**
>
> Get the AUTHORIZATION_CODE and immediately exchange it for access and
>   refresh tokens by sending a POST request to the following address:
>
> https://www.inoreader.com/oauth2/token
>
> Request:
>
> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: www.inoreader.com
>
> Content-length: 217
>
> Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> User-agent: your-user-agent
>
> code=[AUTHORIZATION_CODE]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
>
> Please do not forget to include the Content-type header!

That is, to make a POST request with custom headers as well as passing attribute values.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I didn't get back yet. I've been both away and waiting for Inoreader to get back to me with some details to help proceed with this. I should hopefully get a chance to next week. Pretty confident that the answer is more than acceptable; once I can confirm, I'll be sure to mark the answer as such on here.

Answer (score 1):

To perform an OAuth 2.0 authentication operation in UWP, we usually take advantage of [WebAuthenticationBroker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker).

> The Web Authentication Broker allows applications to use internet authentication and authorization protocols like OpenID or OAuth to connect to online identity providers. An app can choose to use the web authentication broker to sign in to OAuth or OpenID protocol-based web services, such as many social network and picture-sharing websites, provided that the particular service provider has made the necessary changes.

For more information, please see [Web authentication broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker).

The following is a sample with using [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker) class and [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient) class. `WebAuthenticationBroker` class is used for "***Consent page redirection***" and `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` class is used for "***Obtaining access and refresh tokens***".

```
string startURL = "https://www.inoreader.com/oauth2/auth?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&response_type=code&scope=[OPTIONAL_SCOPES]&state=[CSRF_PROTECTION_STRING]";

//endURL is the REDIRECT_URI set in your application registration settings
string endURL = "[REDIRECT_URI]";

System.Uri startURI = new System.Uri(startURL);
System.Uri endURI = new System.Uri(endURL);

// Get Authorization code
var webAuthenticationResult = 
    await Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync( 
    Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationOptions.None, 
    startURI, 
    endURI);

if (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
{
    //webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData would like "https://yourredirecturi.com/?code=[AUTHORIZATION_CODE]&state=[CSRF_PROTECTION_STRING]"
    var decoder = new WwwFormUrlDecoder(new Uri(webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData).Query);
    //Get the CSRF_PROTECTION_STRING and check if it matches that one that you send during the consent page redirection.
    if (decoder.GetFirstValueByName("state") == "[CSRF_PROTECTION_STRING]")
    {
        //Get the AUTHORIZATION_CODE
        var autorizationCode = decoder.GetFirstValueByName("code");

        //Send a POST request
        var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pairs.Add("code", autorizationCode);
        pairs.Add("redirect_uri", [REDIRECT_URI]);
        pairs.Add("client_id", [CLIENT_ID]);
        pairs.Add("client_secret", [CLIENT_SECRET]);
        pairs.Add("scope", [OPTIONAL_SCOPES]);
        pairs.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");

        var formContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

        var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
        var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://www.inoreader.com/oauth2/token"), formContent);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //The Response is a JSON string 
            string jsonString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonObject = Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
            //Obtaining access and refresh tokens
            var accessToken = jsonObject["access_token"].GetString();
            var refreshToken = jsonObject["refresh_token"].GetString();
        }
    }
}
```

While using [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent), it should be able to set `Content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get the token check this link 
https://codeserendipity.com/2017/07/12/oauth2-get-an-access-token-c/

To use the token look at this answer:
[How can I use the access token to get a list of projects from a website in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933933/how-can-i-use-the-access-token-to-get-a-list-of-projects-from-a-website-in-c/44934109#44934109)